# Check if an Azure VM is running

Tags: c#, powershell, azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-management

I want to query an existing azure virtual machine to check whether it is fully deployed and able to be connected to remotely. Is there any way to do this using the Azure Rest API?

I've outlined my current process and why I desire such a call below.

I am using the [Windows Azure management library](http://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.windowsazure.management.libraries) to create a VM using `ComputeManagementClient` and the `CreateDeploymentAsync` function. This then returns a status of Succeeded, if I then do a get on the deployment it has a status of `DeploymentStatus.Running`.

After this has run I am trying to create a remote powershell connection so I can format the disk. I keep getting an error on this as it is unable to create the session.

> WinRM cannot complete the operation. Verify that the specified computer name is valid, that the computer is accessible over the network, and that a firewall exception for the WinRM service is enabled and allows access from this computer. By default, the WinRM firewall exception for public profiles limits access to remote computers within the same local subnet. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.

If I go to the azure management portal the status is provisioning, I assume this is why i cannot create a session.

**Process**

```
CreateAzureVM()
CheckAzureVmCanBeConnectedTo() //I am unable to do this correctly
RunPowershellScriptOnVM() // this fails
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use [Get Deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460804.aspx) to poll for the role's InstanceStatus (note that InstanceStatus != Status). When the InstanceStatus is ReadyRole, you should be able to log into your machine.

There's a distinction between a Deployment status and a Role InstanceStatus. Think of the role as an actual virtual machine, whereas a Deployment may describe multiple VMs.

Answer (score 1):

```
SubscriptionCloudCredentials certificate = new CertificateCloudCredentials(subscriptionId, x509Certificate);

IComputeManagementClient ComputeManagementClient = new ComputeManagementClient(certificate);

var deployments = ComputeManagementClient.Deployments.GetBySlot(hostedServiceName, DeploymentSlot.YourDeploymentSlot);

var state = deployments.RoleInstances.First().PowerState;
```

I hope that this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code it's hard to say exactly what you need to do but I would recommend that you utilise the await keyword to wait for the completion of the call to the Azure API to create the VM.  See the code samples under "Deploy a Virtual Machine" in this MSDN guide: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn722415.aspx#bk_createres