# How to check virtual machine is running or not in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, web-services, virtual-machine

> How to check AZURE virtual machine is running or not in asp.net c# ??? 
>   share code in asp.net c#

Comment: Please, share code in asp.net c#

Comment: if u know then share code.

Comment: First google. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25319123/check-if-an-azure-vm-is-running

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which service provider you need to check:

- For AWS, please create alarm for your VM & refer to CloudWatch API
  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html
- For MS Azure, you can find useful information in the following
  link https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-how-to-monitor/